# SonarLint: Remove the literal "false" boolean value

Tags: java, if-statement, sonarqube, boolean, sonarlint

I get "Remove the literal "false" boolean value." error for the following statement, but I am not sure if there is a possibility to remove false. Any idea?

```
final boolean isDisabled = productMap.get(product.getUuid()) != null ?
                    productMap.get(product.getUuid()) : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably Sonar complies about having a ternary operation with a literal for a boolean operation.

Checking your code I assume productMap values are Boolean, not boolean, thats why you are null checking.

In that case consider the following code for safe unboxing a nullable Boolean

```
final boolean isDisabled = Boolean.TRUE.equals(productMap.get(product.getUuid()));
```

Comment: Yes, you are right and I also faced similar issues for my `boolean` variable. For example when I need to pass null value for my variable, I had to pass false. But the point that I am not sure is should I use `Boolean` for my `boolean` variable when there is a need for null checking or null passing, etc.? I mean my variable on entity and DTO classes is still be `boolean` and I use `Boolean` as much as needed for these situations? Any idea?

Comment: Amigo? Any reply pls?

Comment: You should use boolean wherever you can, and only use Boolean when you have to. If you say that your entity and DTO uses boolean, which cannot be null, when would you ever need to use Boolean?